# Should javascript async function be called with await keyword?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function calling some asynchronous code:

```
async function foo(test){
  const value = await call(test)
}
```

I then call this function from another file without:

```
   foo(5)
```

The linter is throwing a warning saying `Missing await for an async function call`. This does not make sense to me.

The asynchronous code inside the function is called with `await` keyword which makes `foo` run sequentially when called right?

Why is this warning being thrown?

Comment: `foo` can be called without the await keyword, but to use the result of the promise, you'll need to use `await` or `.then`

Comment: It depends on whether you need to wait for `foo()` to finish or not in the caller.

Comment: *"which makes foo run sequentially"*: how else could a JS function run? What do you mean with sequentially? As opposed to what?

Comment: what result of the promise? `value` ?

Comment: This is a linter warning, not a JavaScript error. Usually async functions should be awaited, but it depends on the use case.

Comment: I should have phrased it better. What I meant is that once the await call finishes inside `foo`, then there is no code being executed asynchronously anymore correct?

Comment: @bcsta `async` is syntactic sugar that makes a function return a Promise that resolves with whatever the function's return value is, or reject with whatever error is thrown. Similarly, `await` is syntactic sugar that acts like `.then()` without needing the function chaining usually associated with `then`. Whether you use async/await or have a function that returns a "real" promise and code that `.then().catch()`es the result is basically the same thing, using different syntax. The linter error isn't great though, it's really just "be careful: your code is getting a Promise, not a value!"

Answer (score 3):

> Should javascript async function be called with await keyword?

That depends. If you want the logic where the code is calling `foo()` to wait until `foo` has completed its asynchronous work, then yes, you should use `await`.

If you *don't* want the logic at the call site to wait for `foo` to finish its work, don't use `await`, but **do** store the promise it provides and `await` (or otherwise use it) at some point. Otherwise, you won't handle it if the promise is rejected, and not handling promise rejections is a source of bugs.

So either (in an `async` function):

```
await foo();
```

or (in a non-`async` function):

```
return foo(); // Let the caller handle the promise
```

or (in a non-`async` function where you can't return the promise to your caller):

```
foo()
.then(value => {
    // ...use value (except your `foo` doesn't return one,
    // so really this is just "foo worked")...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

etc.

Fundamentally, though: An `async` function returns a promise, so you should do *something* to handle that promise (by passing it back to your caller, or handling it locally, etc.).

Let's look at what happens in an `async` function calling `foo` when `call` fails, both with and without `await`:

With `await`:

```js
async function call(test) {
    if (test === undefined) {
        throw new Error("'test' is required");
    }
    // Stand-in for something asynchrojous using `test`
    const result = await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(test * 2);
        }, 10);
    });
    return result;
}

async function foo(test) {
    const value = await call(test)
    console.log(`foo got value: ${value}`);
}

async function example() {
    foo();
}

example()
.then(() => {
    console.log("All done, no errors");
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error: " + error);
});
```

When you run that, it says "All done, no errors" but if you look in the devtools console, you'll see "Uncaught (in promise) Error: 'test' is required" (an unhandled rejection).

Compare with using `await`:

```js
async function call(test) {
    if (test === undefined) {
        throw new Error("'test' is required");
    }
    // Stand-in for something asynchrojous using `test`
    const result = await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(test * 2);
        }, 10);
    });
    return result;
}

async function foo(test) {
    const value = await call(test)
    console.log(`foo got value: ${value}`);
}

async function example() {
    await foo();
}

example()
.then(() => {
    console.log("All done, no errors");
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

As you can see, the error from `call` was caught (it propagated from `call` to `foo`, then from `foo` to `example`, then from `example` to where we call it and handle errors).

Comment: It seems like it might be declared `async` just so it can use `await` internally, and the promise that returns is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar - The promise tells us when it finishes, and separately tells us whether it failed, even when you don't return a value.

Comment: Consider the case of an async IIFE, which is just used so you can use `await` within its body.

Comment: This means that there will be a chain of async-await functions all the way to the top of the  execution stack?

Comment: And also shouldn't the code inside `foo` stop to wait for `await call()` finishes? If thats the case then when `foo` finally finishes executing there should not be any asynchronous code left right? i.e. promise is always handled by the end of `foo`

Comment: @Barmar - That's fine **if** A) You don't care when it finishes, and B) You have `try`/`catch` around the whole thing. But that's not the common case.

Comment: @bcsta - There's always a chain. It may not be `async` functions (it may be functions using promises explicitly), but there's always a chain (sometimes multiple chains). It's just a matter of where and how you handle them.

Comment: @bcsta - *"And also shouldn't the code inside foo stop to wait for await call() finishes?"* When you call `foo`, here's what happens: It creates a promise, calls `call`, resolves the promise it created to the promise it got from `call`, and then returns the promise it created. Note that the work `call` does **is not done yet** (in the normal case). The promise `foo` returns tells you when that's done (and whether it succeeded). (Re the term: "resolve to" -- I wrote up promise terminology [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).)

Comment: I know how it works. My point is that you may not care when it completes. It wasn't declared `async` so you could `await` it, just so you could `await call()`

Comment: @Barmar - Okay. :-) My point is that fire-and-forget async calls are rare. In the normal case, and what we should be teaching people, you need to use the promise that you get back -- either to wait for the result, handle errors, or propagate errors to the caller. *Not* using `await` fails to handle errors and is one of the most common errors I see in code using `async` functions.

Comment: Indeed, that rarity is why eslint has this warning on by default

Answer (score -2):

When you declare a function `async` it will always return a Promise. When a function returns a Promise you should treat it as if it is asynchronous, and you should figure out if any function that calls this function marked with `async` should wait for that function to complete, or explicitly allow it to run asynchronously if it needs to.

You either need to await your call to `foo` (which would make whatever function you are calling it in also an async function), or use `.then(..)` to execute your code after your call to `foo` succesfully completes. Alternatively if you want the code to execute asynchronously you can explicitly declare this using the syntax of your linter right above the call to `foo(5)`.

Comment: The keyword `async` doesn't make a function run asynchronously.

Comment: The `async` keyword will always return a `Promise`, regardless if it contains any `await` s. As far as I know it is entirely up to the browser if it executes the content of that function immediately or schedules it.

Comment: That's wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/g7L85d1x/ Every browser that correctly implements the specification will print `1`, `2`, `3` in this order.

Comment: Add a `const x = ` before the call to function `f(..)`, log it and observe that it indeed returns a Promise. Just because your browser currently executes it synchronously does not mean it will always do that. If a function is marked `async` you should always treat it as if it is asynchronous.

Comment: _"Just because your browser currently executes it synchronously does not mean it will always do that"_ But it's written in the specs. A browser has to synchronously run the code. Otherwise, it couldn't return a promise. A function has to synchronously run until it returns. Async functions always return a promise. That's correct. But the rest of the first paragraph in your answer is wrong. _"If a function is marked `async` you should always treat it as if it is asynchronous."_ No, you shouldn't. You should understand the code flow of your code.

Comment: After reading some specs I stand corrected. https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-newpromisecapability After copying the execution context it will execute that context before doing anything else, so a function without awaits will be guaranteed to execute before statements after it. I stand by my advice to treat functions with `async` as if they are asynchronous, even if they are not. If you do not remove `async` from a synchronous function and instead squelch linter warnings you introduce hours of pain for future you or a future coworker.

Comment: If a function is marked `async` you should be positive that whatever code uses that function is written in the mindset that that function might be asynchronous, not with the mindset that it currently isn't. If that is not the case, refactoring that function to be actually asynchronous requires future you or a future coworker to check the invocation of that function everywhere, even though the function definition didn't change. The code should have behaved the same, but now it does not and instead causes race conditions.

Comment: Some developers understand the code flow of their code and other developers try to guess the code flow. Obviously, you prefer to be in the second group. Your answer is still wrong and you should avoid to misinform other people. JavaScript is a single-threaded deterministic language. You can always forecast the behavior as long as there are no external factors.

Comment: Some people don't have the time to read and understand every single function in an entire application if they need to make changes, especially if three other deadlines are lined up. Setting up code in such a way that future developers, either me or someone else, are less likely to trip over something that is avoidable is part of my work. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Now I understand, why so many systems get hacked when developers have so many deadlines and don't even know language basics.